# From a cross section to a probability

Tags: homework-and-exercises, interactions, scattering-cross-section, weak-interaction

This is homework problem:
Given the cross-section of a neutrino-electron scattering, what is the probability for a solar neutrino to scatter with a electron as it goes through the center of the Earth?

I'm quiete confused: the dimensions of a cross section are of $L^{-2}$, to get a probability one has to multiply with the area of a section of the earth, if one had to deal with a *flux* of particles covering the complete area. But here there is only one particle!

Answer (score 2):

I thought a cross-section would be $cm^2$, not $cm^{-2}$.

The information you really lack is probably the macroscopic cross section.  That is, $\Sigma = n  \sigma$, where n is the number density of the target objects, in number per cubic centimeter.  Thus, this gives a value of inverse length units.

Using this, you can readily speak in terms of the cumulative probability distribution (CDF).  I would start with the probability of being uncollided.  Once you have that, unity minus that is the probability that it *is* collided.  For instance, you might use this as your start point:

$$ P(0) = 1.0  \\
\frac{dP}{dx} = - \Sigma P(x) \\
P_s(x) = 1 - P(x) $$

For justification, $\Sigma \Delta x$ really *is* a sort of probability, so just put that in calculus terms in a way that makes sense to you.